# How to display different content on callback iteration in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me start of by saying I am mostly unfamiliar with JS. Most of my work is done in Ruby.

I am running [typed.js](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js) on my home page to iterate through 3 messages. As per the [documentation](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js#customization), this library provides it's own callback triggers. I am using the "preStringTyped" trigger that is fired before each string is typed.

What I'm trying to do is to display a different image for each message. How do I display a different image for each message? I am expecting it to possibly be some sort of counter ( if i==1 then etc.) but like I said my JS skills are not very good.

Comment: Not sure about this particular library, but see if you can add parameters in the callback and they might return to you the data you need. Also, you can try the `this` variable, which also might change context inside the callbacks.

Comment: @dave just need to pass "i" as a parameter to my callback. Working now.

Comment: Great. I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typed.js` library supports an index parameter in the callback so you just need to initialize it like this:

```
$(".element").typed({
  //... other options
  callback: function(index) {
    if (index === 0) {
      //etc...
    }
  }
});
```